# Add ActionBar to each webView that i called by each list view

Tags: android, listview, webview

I want to add `ActionBar` to each `webView` that i called by each `listView`. How can I do that?

This is the image of my `webView` that I got after clicking mine first `listView`:

[image: This is the image of my webView that I got after clicking mine first listView]

Please help me to short out this issue.

This is how my `listView` is showing:

[image: This is how my listView is showing]

Here I opened Different static `webView` HTML page by each item click. But all of they are without `ActionBar` how can I add `actionBar`.

Comment: post ur code please

Comment: There is no error with my code you can see the image . I just want to add an ActionBar with my image view and please upvote my question so that i can upload image directly

Answer (score 0):

Is it new Activity? I think you show start to use ToolBar from support library. You can add it in layout. [Toolbar example here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-toolbar-example/)

Comment: Thanks for you response, yes I used tabLayout with View Pager 
I want to add an ActionBar with my WebView that i call each ListView click. solve my this issue

Comment: Can you mark Issue as solved then and vote if it correct answer

Comment: How can i marked issue as solved because it didn't solve yet.